# does getHeight returns value in dp unit?

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

i am trying to get the height occupied by an item in a listview. so i wrote the following code:

```
mLisVieMeineDocs.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            h = mLisVieMeineDocs.getHeight();
            Log.d(TAG, "getHeight :" + h);//returns 108

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mLisVieMeineDocs.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.height = h;
            mLisVieMeineDocs.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

as stated in the code, the "getHeight" returns 108. when i tried to set this value "108" in the layout_height of the container of the listview in the xml file as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivity2mod_linLay_meineDocList_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="108dp"  <<<------
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/versicherungslistsactivity2mod_linLay_meineDocsBar_container">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">

                <!--android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                    android:stackFromBottom="true"-->
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivity2mod_lisVie_meineDocs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

i found that the linearlayout expands to wrap upto 2 items in the listview despit the code above stated that the height of the item in the listview is 108
But, when i change the 108 to 54dp in the xml file

```
android:layout_height="54dp"
```

then the linearlayout expands to to wrap exactly on item in the listview.

so, why "getHeight" returns as double as of the height of the view? why do i need to divide the value returned from "getHeight" to get the exact height of the view

Comment: The height returned isn't returned in dps but pixels. You'll have to do a conversion to get the dps

Answer (score 2):

**Convert from DP to Pixel use below method:**

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return px;
}
```

**Convert from Pixel to DP use below method:**

```
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return dp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert pixel in to dp, see below code.

```
 h = pxToDp(mLisVieMeineDocs.getHeight());

 public static int pxToDp(int px) {
    return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of value in Java is `Pixel`, So you need transform this.

```
public static int dip2px(Context context, float dp) {
    float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
}

public static int px2dip(Context context, float px) {
    float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (px / scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Sometime you should set DP/SP value eg：
`badgeCountTv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);`

`TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX....`